# What's the better way of getting value from an array of objects? Array.filter() alternative?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
const incoming = "disi";
const sexEnumeration = [
  { key: "bebek", label: "ребенок" },
  { key: "erkek", label: "Мужчина" },
  { key: "disi", label: "женская кошка" }
];
let message = sexEnumeration.filter((item) =>
        item.key == incoming ? item.label : false
      )[0].label


console.log(sexEnumeration.filter((item) => item.key == incoming ? item.label : false)[0].label);
```

Is there any better way of getting the message instead of this ugly array filter.

---

**Edit**
Both solutions were good. I will go for Map solution. But I think it's better to use **.find** for small arrays.

I have applied solutions in [a vue example](https://codepen.io/kaanna/pen/BajKPOr).

https://codepen.io/kaanna/pen/BajKPOr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is converting your array to a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for fast lookup. The use of an array seems not really fitting here. This does assume that the item `key` property is unique across items.

```js
const sexEnumeration = [
  { key: "bebek", label: "ребенок" },
  { key: "erkek", label: "Мужчина" },
  { key: "disi", label: "женская кошка" }
];
const sexEnumerationMap = new Map(sexEnumeration.map(item => [item.key, item]));

console.log(sexEnumerationMap.get("disi").label);
console.log(sexEnumerationMap.get("bebek").label);
console.log(sexEnumerationMap.get("erkek").label);
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `Array.filter()`, which returns **all** elements in the `sexEnumeration` array that pass the test implemented within the callback function, you can use [Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), which

> returns the value of the **first** element in the provided array that
>   satisfies the provided testing function

This is how it can be done:

```
const message = (sexEnumeration.find((item) =>
    item.key === incoming ? item.label : false
)).label
```

Here is the working, concise sample (includes the suggestion by @3limin4t0r):

```js
const incoming = "disi";
const sexEnumeration = [
  { key: "bebek", label: "ребенок" },
  { key: "erkek", label: "Мужчина" },
  { key: "disi", label: "женская кошка" }
];

const { label: message } = sexEnumeration.find(({ key }) => (
  key == incoming
));

console.log(message);
```

Comment: Assuming the label can't be empty you could also omit the ternary operator. `sexEnumeration.find(item => item.key === incoming).label`

Comment: @3limin4t0r ahh.. Good catch! Thanks